# Order of coordinates for extent property in layer Tile?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers, coordinates, extents

I was just going through the documentation for OpenLayers 3.11 and came across `Tile()`. Now it accepts a lot of properties: opacity, preload , map, etc.), but the one I am interested in is `extent`. Basically, it allows me to set an extent of which tiles I would like to load, so an initialization with the extent parameter might look like as follows:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: false,
    preload: Infinity,
    extent: [-16655.5402445057125, 6609968.258934638,0,6809968],
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
      key: 'Ak-dzM4wZjSqTlzveKz5u0d4IQ4bRzVI309GxmkgSVr1ewS6iPSrOvOKhA-CJlm3',
      imagerySet: styles[i]
      // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
      // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
      // maxZoom: 19
    })
  })
```

Notice how the `extent` parameter accepts an array with 4 values in it. My question is about getting the correct order of the values inside the extent array.

Comment: MinX,MinY,MaxX,MaxY where X is the axis that goes from left to right on the screen (longitude, easting) and Y from bottom to top (latitude, northing).

Comment: A lot depends on context -- GIS vector folks mostly use llx,lly,urx,ury (aka minx,miny,maxx,maxy) while image folks lean toward ulx,uly,lrx,lry, and non-GIS folks gravitate toward llLat,llLon,urLat,urLon.  In context, this looks like the first usage.

Answer (score 2):

From [ol/layer/Tile](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile.html) documentation, property `extent` is of type [module:ol/extent~Extent](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#~Extent), which reads:

> An array of numbers representing an extent: [minx, miny, maxx, maxy].

`x` coordinates are longitude (easting) and `y` coordinates are latitude (northing).